# How can I change my bots status icon to streaming in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How to I change [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8ldR.png) to the Streaming icon.
So far I have this much:

```
client.user.setActivity('with the Threads of the Universe', { type: ActivityType.Streaming });
```

But how can I change the actual icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you must add status: `'online',` and you can change this on
`status: "idle"` // online, idle, invisible, dnd

```js
client.user.setActivity('with the Threads of the Universe', { type: ActivityType.Streaming status: 'online', });
```

and if you need stream Status use this

```js
client.user.setActivity("Hello world.", {
  type: "STREAMING",
  url: "https://www.twitch.tv/yourchannle"
});
```